# is it necessary/allowed to manually update iAd

Tags: objective-c

My app loads iAd with first user action but then seems to stay static afterwards

1: will the iAd always refresh itself? And is it possible to change the rate manually?

2: when running on my own devices with test ads: can I somehow see how many impressions that is counted in any one session?

I have been searching around a lot, and found very mixed and weak answers to questions like these and I think solid answers would be relevant to a lot of people out there.